# a function that takes single ("a1b2c3") string and return string like ’abc, 123’ recursively

Tags: python

how could I solve it, when  I just return first and last individually it gives "abc" and "123". And when I concatenate them it gives "abc32c31bc32c3".

```
def unzip(s1):
#base case

if len(s1) == 0:
    return s1
else:
    # str1 =str1+ s1[0]
    # str2 = s1[1]
    first = s1[0] + unzip(s1[2:])
    last  = s1[1]+unzip(s1[2:])
    return first+last
```

Comment: Does it need to be recursive? Would `f"{s1[::2]}, {s1[1::2]}"` suffice?

Comment: You really need to clarify your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this one:

```py
def unzip(s1):
    #base case
    if len(s1) < 2:
        return s1, ''
    else:
        first, last = s1[0], s1[1]
        first_, last_ = unzip(s1[2:])
        return first + first_, last + last_

unzip('a1b2c3')
```

Edit: I just realized that the function also works without the base case `len(s1) == 2`, as it's covered by the recursive case.

Edit 2: Improved efficiency, the recursive call needs to be done only once.